# User permissions for creating PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on Ubuntu. Following is one of my commands.

```
$ psql -U kuser -d postgres
```

Then this connects to the database. But from postgres terminal when i try

```
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE kdb;
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

When I try a similar command in Ubuntu, it gives the following

```
$ sudo -u kuser createdb kdb
sudo: unknown user: kuser
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

How do I create this DB?. I have sudo rights and kuser is not me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It appears you have a database user named `kuser`, but there is no system user with that name. This is why you're able to get a postgres prompt, but sudo fails.

That user isn't able to create a database because the account doesn't have the `createdb` permission.

You can either grant that permission to the user using the `postgres` account (the default management account on Ubuntu):

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'alter user kuser with createdb' postgres
```

Or just use that management account to create the database and specify that it is owned by the `kuser` account:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb -O kuser kdb
```

If that user isn't going to be creating other databases I'd advise using the latter option, better to limit the privileges that are granted to the account.

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql -c 'alter user USER_NAME with createdb' postgres` saved my day :)